# Custom search without publishing content as post/pages

Tags: wordpress, search, plugins, customization

I have 200k titles along-with URLs in an excel sheet and I want to place them on my wordpress website so users can search the desired content. When it comes to results, it should be shown in two columns [title and URL].
My intension is to keep it away from my post/pages kind of data and I don't want it to be publshed as post/pages so wordpress default search can search it. I want to have a custom search plugin/code that can make it happen without disturbing wordpress website at all.
If any of you do have any idea, please help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks for your time